# How to read flask sessions using javascript?

Tags: javascript, session, angularjs, flask

I have a secured flask session

```
session = "xC4tHoSZQVSHpVtnHUONYb/obAA=?USER_TOKEN=UycuZUp3Rndja1JnREFJQU1CZThwWVpqbkRWNHZpQW9QMlg0TzY5ZXN4MU5rTlZOaEM5RERuczBCRkRqSHFDY0YxTGZMSUM3WlNHdkxhZEpJUjZXcjh4ekZyUEQ5aUxFMEEuVGt0V3RqdTFKblVBVzV2SnRpSjd3M0NJZFdRJwpwMQou"
```

I am using [angular.js](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies.%24cookies) cookies to retrieve the value but it gives me nothing.

```
console.log('token - ' + $cookieStore.get('USER_TOKEN'));
```

How can I access the value of `USER_TOKEN` using Javascript?

Answer (score 1):

I could be completely contradicted on this, but I've been of the understanding that you can't access the session data with Javascript because of some of the internals that the Werkzeug secure cookie module uses. I've got plans to try out this snippet as a workaround:

http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/51/

But until I get a chance to try it I wouldn't know whether or not it could do some of the things lacking with the basic session module of Flask.

Comment: My cookies are secure and signed by `itsdangerous`, but I don't know how to get the data out on the browser for read purposes

Comment: Can you post your controller that shows everything you're injecting? Also, is it available via $cookies instead of $cookieStore?

Answer (score 1):

Since the question was asked Flask switched to itsdangerous client side sessions by default.

As this is still the top google result for this question and i had some problems figuring it out myself, here is how to do it nowadays:

```
function parse_session(){
    var cookie = Cookies('session');
    if(! cookie) return;
    // Is the content ziped ?
    var un_64 = "";
    if(cookie[0] == "."){
        var data = cookie.split('.')[1].replace(/_/g, '/').replace(/-/g, '+');
        un_b64 = atob(data);
        un_b64 = pako.inflate(un_b64, {to: 'string'});
    }else{
        var data = cookie.split('.')[0].replace(/_/g, '/').replace(/-/g, '+');
        un_b64 = atob(data);
    }
    return jQuery.parseJSON(un_b64);
}
```

This snippet uses jquery, cookie.js and paco (to unzip).
Flasks 'SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY' config variable need to be set to False to be able to read the session on the client side.

Answer (score 0):

Alright. for accessing the cookie session which is set by the flask. we can't directly access in js using document.cookies as it HttpOnly. However, you can access it using the template engine syntax.

```
let session = {{session|tojson}};
```